# Elasticsearch Hash Child Query does not work when using with Child item v: 5.6

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using parent-child relationship in Elasticsearch 5.6 cluster

İn my case I have a tree like

1. Post (an object)
2. Comment (comments of a post)
3. CommentBlock (blocked users of a comment)

I don't want to get blocked comments by user when I search the comments

in nest I am using this query;

& q.Bool(b => b.MustNot(m => m.HasChild(hs => hs.Query(qq => qq.Term(tt => tt.MemberId, MemberId))))))

this query did not work.

When I write has child query for a parent it is ok but
When I write has child query for a child ( child of child) i does not work

Thanks for your helps

Comment: I'm trying to understand how `CommentBlock` relate to `Comment` - whether a comment is blocked or not seems like it could be implemented as a property on `Comment`. Perhaps a small code example of your structure would help?

Comment: Hi sory for late reply. As you think comment is blocked. But some user can block the comment and some users not. so some of the user will continue see the comment and some of the user will not see the commetn who are blocked the comment. So I am keeping these users in a list "CommentBlock" which is a child item of  Comment.

Comment: What properties besides a User ID does a `CommentBlock` have? Seems like this could be implemented as list of blocked User IDs on a comment